# Laravel using routes within html

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to write an `index.html` page that will load for 3 seconds then move to `homepage.blade.php`

this is my JavaScript

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href  ="{ url('/homepage') }";
}, 3000);
```

I have the following route

```
Route::get('/homepage', function () {
    return  view('homepage');
})->name('homepage');
```

when I run this I get `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` 
can anybody help

and I have my view `homepage.blade.php` in views directory with `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Your `url('/homepage')` function call isn't correctly wrapped inside of `{{ }}`. You only have a single curly brace surrounding your function call, instead of double curly braces. So the output to the page will literally be:

```
window.location.href  = "{ url('/homepage') }";
```

and not

```
window.location.href  = "http://example.com/homepage";
```

like you want.

I'm also assuming that your JavaScript is placed inside a blade template file. That's the only way your `url()` function would work.